# Could not access HTTP invoker remote service

Tags: java, oracle, spring

i'm working in a kofax application connected with oracle database.
i found an error as

```
ERROR markview.viewer.MvViewer  
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [ias9:opmn:ormi://uhmvtst.uhhs.com:6003:markview_tst4/mvas/remote/EnterpriseService]; nested exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ias9
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:211)
```

i'm getting as connection failed to open. could any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring HTTP invoker is for HTTP. It's not going to work with that URL you gave it (ias9:opmn:ormi://uhmvtst.uhhs.com:6003:markview_tst4/mvas/remote/EnterpriseService)